# How to get the closest point from the known point to a fractal tree？

Tags: equation-solving, geometry, fractals, distance

Given a known point, how to analytically find the nearest point from the point to the fractal tree?

The fractal tree code:

```
gan[t_List] := Block[{zuo = N[{{Cos[y], -Sin[y]}, {Sin[y], Cos[y]}}], you = N[{{Cos[y], Sin[y]}, {-Sin[y], Cos[y]}}], n = Length[t], a, b, c, d, e}, jied = {}; 
For[i = 1, i <= n, i++,
   ti = t[[i]];
   a = ti[[1]];
   e = ti[[2]];
   b = k (e - a) + a; c = b + r (zuo.(b - a)); 
   d = b + r (you.(b - a)); 
   jied = Join[jied, {{b, c}, {b, e}, {b, d}}]; 
   gjd = Join[gjd, {{a, b}}]]; jied]; 
huaye[u_List] := Block[{m = Length[u], i, xian = {}}, 
  For[i = 1, i <= m, i++, 
   AppendTo[xian, {Thickness[0.017], Line[u[[i]]]}]]; xian]; 
huagan[v_, t_] := Block[{ggxian = {}, i, j, p, s}, 
  For[i = 0, i < t, i++, p = Sum[3^s, {s, 0, i}]; 
   For[j = p - 3^i + 1, j <= p, j++, 
    AppendTo[ggxian, {Thickness[0.007 + 0.005 (t - i)], Line[v[[j]]]}]]]; ggxian]
shuzhi[jiaodu_, bili_, cishu_, zchang_] := Module[{}, gjd = {}; jied = {}; y = jiaodu Degree; k = bili; r = zchang; Nest[gan, {{{0, 0}, {0, 10}}}, cishu]; 
  shugan = huagan[gjd, cishu]; 
  shuye = huaye[jied]; 
  Show[Graphics[{shugan, shuye}], AspectRatio -> Automatic]]; 
  shuzhi[60, 1/3, 5, 1]
```

[image: the fractal tree]

Comment: If you can not specify all points of the tree in closed form, how do you want to specify the nearest point. It may need an infinite recursion.